# Web publishing system with code highlighting

Tags: apache, web-applications, syntax-highlighting

I'd like to publish some of the many programs I've written on the web.
Is there a syntax highlighting Linux web publishing application (CMS/Blog/RoR app)
that displays syntax for C++, Python,  Bash scripts, SQL, VBA, awk,
Erlang, java, makefiles, Ruby, Pascal and other languages?

The more syntax settings configuration files, the better.

The extensions I have in Textpad (for which I have syntax highlighting -- syn files) are
.as, .asm, .asp, .awk, .bas, .bat, .c, .conf,
.cpp, .cs, .ctl, .dfm, .dsc, .erl,
.fnc, .h, .hpp, .inf, .ini, .jav, .java,
.mak, .nsh, .nsi, .ora, .pas, .pkb, .pks,
.pl, .prc, .py, .reg, .rsp, .sh, .sql, .syn,
.tcl, .trg, .vw, .xml, .xsl, .xslfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 100% JavaScript solutions for this so it can be independent of the CMS.

Example: [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter)

[And here's a list...](http://www.webdesignbooth.com/9-useful-javascript-syntax-highlighting-scripts/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the Joomla CMS: http://www.joomla.org/

It has built-in support for Geshi: http://qbnz.com/highlighter/

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/ is pretty nice.